# MySQL: Grant **all** privileges on database

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-error-1142

I've created database, for example 'mydb'.

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*HASH';
GRANT ALL ON mydb.* TO 'myuser'@'%';
GRANT ALL ON mydb TO 'myuser'@'%';
GRANT CREATE ON mydb TO 'myuser'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now i can login to database from everywhere, but can't create tables.

How to grant all privileges on that database and (in the future) tables. I can't create tables in 'mydb' database. I always get:

```
CREATE TABLE t (c CHAR(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin);
ERROR 1142 (42000): CREATE command denied to user 'myuser'@'...' for table 't'
```

Comment: You should use `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` only if you modify the grant tables directly using statements such as `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE`

Answer (score 1044, accepted):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'myuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

This is how I create my "Super User" privileges (although I would normally specify a host).

## IMPORTANT NOTE

While this answer can solve the problem of access, `WITH GRANT OPTION` creates a MySQL user that can [edit the permissions of other users](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_grant-option).

> The GRANT OPTION privilege enables you to give to other users or remove from other users those privileges that you yourself possess.

For security reasons, you should not use this type of user account for any process that the public will have access to (i.e. a website). It is recommended that you [create a user with only database privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15707789/2370483) for that kind of use.

Answer (score 571):

This is old question but I don't think the accepted answer is safe. It's good for creating a super user but not good if you want to grant privileges on a single database.

```
grant all privileges on mydb.* to myuser@'%' identified by 'mypasswd';
grant all privileges on mydb.* to myuser@localhost identified by 'mypasswd';
```

`%` seems to not cover socket communications, that the `localhost` is for. `WITH GRANT OPTION` is only good for the super user, otherwise it is usually a security risk.

**Update** for MySQL 5.7+ seems like this warns about:

> Using GRANT statement to modify existing user's properties other than
> privileges is deprecated and will be removed in future release. Use
> ALTER USER statement for this operation.

So setting password should be with separate commands. Thanks to comment from @scary-wombat.

```
ALTER USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
ALTER USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
```

Comment: +1 for not including `WITH GRANT OPTION` and targeting a specified database instead of all (`*`).

Comment: Note that you probably don't need the first command unless you want access from outside IP addresses, or from other computers on the local subnet.

If you do, I would recommend using commands that are targeted to the specific IP addresses that you want to allow, such as myuser@192.168.0.1 (for one on the local subnet), rather than myuser@% generally.

Comment: @EvanDonovan, there are a lot of things here that depend on use case as well environment. For example java driver does not support socket transport at all IIRC. But generally I agree - better specify specific IPs when possible, or run server only on `127.0.0.1` and firewall the server when listening to non-localhost.

Answer (score 158):

This will be helpful for some people:

From MySQL command line:

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Sadly, at this point newuser has no permissions to do anything with the databases. In fact, if newuser even tries to login (with the password, password), they will not be able to reach the MySQL shell.

Therefore, the first thing to do is to provide the user with access to the information they will need.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
```

The asterisks in this command refer to the database and table (respectively) that they can access—this specific command allows to the user to read, edit, execute and perform all tasks across all the databases and tables.

Once you have finalized the permissions that you want to set up for your new users, always be sure to reload all the privileges.

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Your changes will now be in effect.

For more information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html

If you are not comfortable with the command line then you can use a client like [MySQL workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/), [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com) or [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com)

Comment: `flush privileges` is not needed when you use `grant` commands. [x4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016505/mysql-grant-all-privileges-on-database/26244137#comment44277771_26244137)

Comment: Either you wholesale copied from Linode, or they copied from you: https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mysql/install-mysql-phpmyadmin-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I needed to identify again with `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost'  IDENTIFIED BY 'my_password' WITH GRANT OPTION;` (strange... , but true)

Answer (score 35):

1. Create the database

```
CREATE DATABASE db_name;
```

2. Create the username for the database db_name

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_name.* TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

3. Use the database

```
USE db_name;
```

4. Finally you are in database db_name and then execute the commands like create , select and insert operations.

Answer (score 24):

This SQL grants on all databases but just basic privileges. They're enough for Drupal or Wordpress and as a nicety, allows one developer account for local projects.

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, 
    INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES 
ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Answer (score 23):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO myuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'mypasswd';
```

Works for privileges on schema :)

Optional: after `mypasswd` you can add `WITH GRANT OPTION`

Answer (score 18):

I could able to make it work only by adding `GRANT OPTION`, without that always receive permission denied error

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Answer (score 16):

Hello I used this code to have the super user in mysql

```
GRANT EXECUTE, PROCESS, SELECT, SHOW DATABASES, SHOW VIEW, ALTER, ALTER ROUTINE,
    CREATE, CREATE ROUTINE, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, CREATE VIEW, DELETE, DROP,
    EVENT, INDEX, INSERT, REFERENCES, TRIGGER, UPDATE, CREATE USER, FILE,
    LOCK TABLES, RELOAD, REPLICATION CLIENT, REPLICATION SLAVE, SHUTDOWN,
    SUPER
        ON *.* TO mysql@'%'
    WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

and then

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: `flush privileges` is not needed when you use `grant` commands. [x4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016505/mysql-grant-all-privileges-on-database#comment44277812_5016505)

Comment: Note:  The exact list in the `GRANT` varies between Versions of MySQL.

Answer (score 13):

I had this challenge when working on **MySQL  Ver 8.0.21**

I wanted to grant permissions of a database named `my_app_db` to the `root` user running on `localhost` host.

But when I run the command:

```
use my_app_db;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_app_db.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

I get the error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'my_app_db.* TO 'root'@'localhost'' at line 1>

**Here's how I fixed**:

Login to your MySQL console. You can change `root` to the **user** you want to login with:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Enter your **mysql root password**

Next, list out all the users and their host on the MySQL server. Unlike PostgreSQL this is often stored in the `mysql` database. So we need to select the `mysql` database first:

```
use mysql;
SELECT user, host FROM user;
```

**Note**: if you don't run the `use mysql`, you get the `no database selected` error.

This should give you an output of this sort:

```
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Next, based on the information gotten from the list, grant privileges to the user that you want. We will need to first select the database before granting permission to it. For me, I am using the `root` user that runs on the `localhost` host:

```
use my_app_db;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

**Note**: The `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'root'@'localhost';` command may not work for modern versions of MySQL. Most modern versions of MyQL replace the `database_name` with `*` in the **grant privileges** command after you select the database that you want to use.

You can then exit the MySQL console:

```
exit
```

That's it.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 8):

To access from remote server to  mydb database only

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'root'@'192.168.2.21';
```

To access from remote server to all databases.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'root'@'192.168.2.21';
```

Answer (score 8):

To grant all priveleges on the database: `mydb` to the user: `myuser`, just execute:

```
GRANT ALL ON mydb.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
```

or:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
```

The `PRIVILEGES` keyword is not necessary.

Also I do not know why the other answers suggest that the `IDENTIFIED BY 'password'` be put on the end of the command. I believe that it is not required.