# PHP script wont connect to database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

When certain pages load on my site I have a script that will add points to the users table in the points row.  Here is my script

```
<?php

session_start();
$db = mysqli_connect("hostname", "username", "password", "database");

$username = $_SESSION['username']; 

mysqli_query($db, 'UPDATE login_users SET points_column=points_column+1 WHERE username=$username');


?>
```

I have already checked the host name, username and password details and everything is correct but I keep getting this error

> Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'a5950626_jlf'@'10.1.1.34' (using password: YES) in /home/a5950626/public_html/application/home.php on line 5
>
> PHP Error Message
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean
>   given in /home/a5950626/public_html/application/home.php on line 9

Any ideas what the problem could be or how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: no for security, it just says hostname, username, password and database name

Comment: The Fix is =>: Access denied for user.... To Fix it take shure, you are allowed to connect by foreign ip (not localhost) and the password is correct ....

Comment: `Access denied for user 'a5950626_jlf'@'10.1.1.34' (using password: YES) in /home/a5950626/public_html/application/home.php on line 5` indicates that your credentials are **not** fine.

Comment: It is possible, that you are trying to connect to databese form outside the db server, and your db user have no permission to connect from outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the error message clearly says that access is denied, so either hostname/username/password/database is wrong or the user doesn't have the required permissions.

How to set up permissions, in this example all:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name TO user@host IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Host is where you'd be connecting from. `%` can be used as a wildchar. See more detailed examples at the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html). (you can see your user + host in the error message, btw)

As a side note, you should check that connection was successful before trying to use the database link in a query.

Comment: How can I add permissions to all users in my table? Thanks by the way :)

Comment: Here is another question that should help you too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016505/mysql-grant-all-privileges-on-database