# mysql db_connect function from live server is not working

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am tring to connect mySQL db hosted on a live server
the line of code to connect db is

```
mysql_connect("example.com", "webwork_odesk1", "xxxxxxxx" , "webwork1_odesk") or die("Couldn't make connection.");
```

The username and password are correct but the error displaying in browser is

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'webwork_odesk1'@'119.154.3.131' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\index.php on line 4
```

Couldn't make connection.

How I can fix this problem

Comment: I hope those aren't your real login details.

Comment: these aren't the real. but I am using the real one

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions as they are in the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Perhaps check that your mysql server and mysql user allows external connections, perhaps its also bound to only listen to internal loopback connection, `127.0.0.1/localhost`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13036780/php-script-wont-connect-to-database/13036828).

Like I said there, "Access denied for user 'webwork_odesk1'@'119.154.3.131' (using password: YES)"-messages come from two things - either hostname/username/password/database is wrong or the user doesn't have the required permissions. Check that user has the right permissions.

Answer (score 1):

It probably has to do with the MySql Server permissions. Probably it doesn't accept connections from outside. You can shortly test this by uploading the script and using localhost to connect to the database server.