# Create new user in mysql with access to only certain databases

Tags: mysql

Dont know if this is possible.

I need to create a new mysql user with access to only databases with database name with prefix say **user_db_**.

I have a php application in which when a new user is added it creates a database **user_db_**'userid'. Suppose three users are created such that their databases are **user_db_1**, **user_db_2**, **user_db_3**.

I need to create a new user say **user_accounts** which has access to only **user_db_1**, **user_db_2**, **user_db_3**,..........,**user_db_n**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: Grant \*\*all\*\* privileges on database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016505/mysql-grant-all-privileges-on-database)

Answer (score 6):

Use the following code for granting privileges on a particular DB.

```
grant all privileges on DB_NAME.* to 'USER'@'REMOTE_IP' identified by 'PASSWORD';
```

Answer (score 3):

There are the three steps

1. Create Database
2. Create new User
3. Give the rights with grant all command

Like this

```
CREATE DATABASE DBTEST
```

If this is run successfully without any error, then create new user

```
CREATE USER 'NEWUSER'@'LOCALHOST' IDENTIFIED BY 'NEWUSERPASSWORD'
```

After user creation give the right of create table drop table

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'NEWUSER'@'LOCALHOST'
```

And after all give one command

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

**Update 31/03/2015** (as it stated in comments)

You can give the rights on particular database like this

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DBTEST.* TO 'NEWUSER'@'LOCALHOST
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you can use a combination of

```
SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'user_db_%'
```

to get a current list of user databases, and

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'hostname' ...
```

to create a user, and

```
GRANT ALL ON user_db_N.* TO 'username'@'hostname'
```

to set database privileges to the user for each of databases you get from `SHOW DATABASES`.

Comment: actually its not like that the databases can be created after i set this privailage also. So its only possible to create privilage with prefix.

Comment: What do you mean by "...its not like that the databases can be created after i set this privilege..."? What you certainly will need to do is to reassign privileges for your user_accounts user for newly created databases each time you create them.

Comment: Hey Peter. I understand what you're saying. Does this mean there's no way to easily give a user permission to multiple but not all databases at the same time?