# How do I create a user with the same privileges as root in MySQL/MariaDB?

Tags: mysql

How do I create a user with the same privileges as root in  MySQL/MariaDB?.

Comment: try to google it: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016505/mysql-grant-all-privileges-on-database

Answer (score 192):

```
% mysql --user=root mysql
CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
CREATE USER 'monty'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost';
GRANT RELOAD,PROCESS ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost';
CREATE USER 'dummy'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Can you expand on why you create `'localhost'` and `'%'` users?

Comment: The 'monty'@'localhost' account can be used only when connecting from the local host. The 'monty'@'%' account uses the '%' wildcard for the host part, so it can be used to connect from any host

Comment: @takeshin, `%` doesn't seem to include `localhost` does it?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html should answer your questions.

Comment: I had to run `$ mysql -u root -p` and then enter root password to be able to start the MySQL command line

Comment: I had issues with wildcare `%`, but MariaDB doc's state `If the host name is not provided, it is assumed to be '%'.` so I created a user without `@host` and one for `@localhost` and that did the trick, not sure why mariadb wouldn't take my %