# Mysql Connection with out password using corejava program

Tags: java, mysql

I want to connect to a MySQL database. While installing MySQL I did not give any password, so in my program I did the same but I am getting error on connection. I am using properties file to get the driver, URL, username and password. Help me pleas.

This is my code:

```
try
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/easylibdb1","root","");
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    System.out.println("Got Error While Connecting To Database...!");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is my properties file content:

```
driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.51:3306/easylibdb1
user=root
password=""
```

Comment: can you show the stacktrace ?

Comment: i am getting like error: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.1.37' (using password: NO)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`using password: NO` - this means the program is **not** passing any password, in your case that is correct.

Since you mention that you are reading the values from the properties file, I don't see you doing that in the code you have posted. If you are really **reading the values from the properties file in your actual code**, and the MySQL server is a **remote server**, then make sure that you **grant relevant permissions** on the remote MySQL server with the below statement

`grant all privileges on easylibdb1.* to 'root'@'192.168.1.51'` to allow connections originating from 192.168.1.51

or

`grant all privileges on easylibdb1.* to 'root'@'%'` to allow connections originating from anywhere

Answer (score 3):

The password argument should be set to `null` because even an empty String `""` implies that there is a password.

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/easylibdb1","root",null)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass `null` as password instead of an empty String. That should make it work.

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/easylibdb1","root",null);
```

From what I see right now, you're actually not using the values from the properties file.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the 2 quotes after password in your properties file.
So `password=""`should be `password=`

Comment: sorry i am stil geting this error : java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.1.37' (using password: NO)

Answer (score 0):

If it's really `password=""` what stands in your properties file, then `""` will be sent as password. Not an empty string but the two quote signs.

Answer (score 0):

```
URL=jdbc\:mysql\://192.168.1.51:3306/easylibdb1
USER=root
PASSWD=
DRIVER=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Please set ur PASSWORD Field as blank.. Don't put quote.

Comment: ya i did that but still i am getting like  java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.1.37' (using password: NO)

Comment: So, you won't be access of the that particular IP address. Check the grant of the mysql.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016505/mysql-grant-all-privileges-on-database

Answer (score 0):

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/easylibdb1","root",null);
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain the code. If you do explain it (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner actually learns something!

Answer (score 0):

According to you, you are passing username as root and password as empty string.And your connection is established through

```
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/easylibdb1","root","");
```

So change your function as

```
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/easylibdb1","root",null);
```

Then it will work.
Or change the password in the `application.properties` file as

```
password=
```

Answer (score -1):

You have left the password field empty. However, for connecting to a MySQL database, you typically need to provide a valid password.

In your case, you can pass "null" as the password and it should do the trick.

```
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/easylibdb1","root",null)
```

But generally, having a password improves security. Hope this helps!

Comment: Answers generated by ChatGPT are banned.