# Mysql Connection with out password using corejava program (getting Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' )

Tags: java, mysql

i wanted to connect for mysql database, while installing mysql i not gave any password, so  in my program i did the same but i am getting error on connection. I am using properties file to get driver,url,username and password help me pleas.

this is my code,

```
try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/easylibdb1","root","");

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Got Error While Connecting To Database...!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

this is my properties file content,

driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.51:3306/easylibdb1

user=**root**

password=**""**

and stack trace is as fallow..

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:910)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3923)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1273)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2031)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:718)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
    at com.easylib.AccessionFormat.mySqlConnection(AccessionFormat.java:111)
    at com.easylib.Index.main(Index.java:12)
```

Comment: `con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306 easylibdb1","root",null);`

Comment: If on Unix than try in Terminal `mysql -u root` if it connects

Comment: that's ok, i am geting like this error: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.1.37' (using password: NO)

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of: [Mysql Connection with out password using corejava program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208146/mysql-connection-with-out-password-using-corejava-program/17208295#17208295)

And you're still using the double quotes as password.

You should replace `password=""` with `password=`

and/or

replace `con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/easylibdb1","root","");` with `con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/easylibdb1","root",null);`

Comment: that's ok, i am geting like this error: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.1.37' (using password: NO)

Answer (score 0):

I think the root user don't have permissions to access the database. so you need to give the access by `grant` option in mysql. Execute the following in your mysql command line.

```
GRANT ALL ON easylibdb1.* TO 'root'@'%';
```

I hope it will work.