# Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm trying to setup a JPA connection to via hibernate but i don't get what's the problem with my code.

**My Configuration:**

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JPAConfig {
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean =
                new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource =
                new DriverManagerDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("root");
        driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("");
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/odontology");
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(driverManagerDataSource);

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(properties);
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("org.odontology.models");

        return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory){
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

**This is the error i get:**

```
    org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
```

Comment: Is your database running (properly)? Can you connect to it from a shell or something else?

Comment: yes, im access database with command "sudo mysql -u root"

Answer (score 0):

I think you are setting "" as password. Try without invoking driverManagerDataSource.setPassword or with driverManagerDataSource.setPassword(null)

Also, check this question: [Mysql Connection with out password using corejava program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208146/mysql-connection-with-out-password-using-corejava-program/17208295#17208295)