# MySQLWorkbench: getting "access denied. show databases permission needed" error

Tags: mysql

so I'm trying to connect to a MySQL 5.1.x server remotely using a recent version of MySQLWorkbench (6.3.6).

I have run these commands on the MySQL prompt:

```
use mysql;
grant all privileges on mydb.*  to 'myuser'@'%' identified by 'mypassword';
flush privileges;
```

and I can connect to the schema/DB using workbench but I cannot get a listing of the tables/other schema objects.

This is the exact response I'm getting:

```
Error Code: 1227 Access denied; you need the SHOW DATABASES privilege for this operation
```

This is the response I'm getting from show grants. I ran this as root user on the localhost. I've obfuscated any info that might identify my DB.

```
mysql> show grants for 'mydb'@'%';
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for mydb@%                                                                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'mydb'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'mypassword' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mydb`.* TO 'mydb'@'%'                                                      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any ideas on how to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With this line

```
grant all privileges on mydb.* ...
```

you are giving privileges to your user to every table in the `mydb` database. `SHOW DATABASES` however is a global privilege, not affected by above line.

You can run below to also allow the SHOW DATABASES command:

```
GRANT SHOW DATABASES ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%'
```

Comment: is there ways an option so in the app so I don't show other databases objects? I don't really care for them. Only the objects within the database where I have access. :)

Comment: So you only want to see the tables in `mydb`? @mrjayviper -- If so, use `show tables in mydb;`

Comment: but not gonna help me with my mysqlworkbench issue? mysqlworkbench won't even list the objects in the database where I have access.

Comment: Sure it will. @mrjayviper -- Why not?

Comment: please see link. objects normally appear here. I can't see them. http://i.imgur.com/ObunO1F.jpg

Comment: Ahh, now I get it. No, you'll need to run the command I posted in my answer. Thereafter, you can hide all the databases you don't want to see. See this answer on howto http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392133/user-cannot-see-databases-in-mysql-workbench