# Database permits main user 'in' but cannot 'see' any schemas

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm on RDS and this is the situation:

Unable to progress with my RDS instance.

RDS instance master user is 'admin'

1. Can connect up to the instance using the admin user (MySQL WB or commandLine):

```
C:\Users\xx>mysql -u 'admin'  -p --host=md-blahblah-db-instance.blahblah.ap-southeast-rds.amazonaws.com
Enter password: ********
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  etc etc
Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

2. Now I'm in but (on MySQL WB or commandLine) cannot 'see' schema:

```
mysql> use uxxx
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'fxxxx.lnk.telstra.net' to database 'uxxx'
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON umb.* TO 'admin'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'fxxxx.lnk.telstra.net'  to database 'uxxx'
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON umb.* TO 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepass';
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'fxxxx.lnk.telstra.net'  to database 'uxxx'
mysql> CREATE USER test identified by 'password';
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation
mysql> flush privileges;
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the RELOAD privilege(s) for this operation
```

Have tried using ideas from the accepted answer at [User cannot see databases in mysql workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392133/user-cannot-see-databases-in-mysql-workbench)
but can't progress as can't create another user.
[MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw) suggests that I have could possibly have another user named admin@'fxxxx.lnk.telstra.net', hence this problem.

Quoting:

> Hence, such an anonymous user would "mask" any other user like '[any_username]'@'%' when connecting from localhost.
>
> 'bill'@'localhost' does match 'bill'@'%', but would match (e.g.) ''@'localhost' beforehand.

The recommended solution is to drop this anonymous user (this is usually a good thing to do anyways).

Reluctant to start again as a lot of CloudFormation stacks are associated with this database.
Any ideas? Appreciate all help.

Comment: It seems to me that maybe you have to specify the database more specifically, not just **uxxx**

Comment: Sorry, actually the uxxx was the same as the umb. Thanks