# node.js mysql error: ECONNREFUSED

Tags: mysql, node.js, econnrefused

Why can't I connect to the mysql server?

On the same server an Apache/PHP server is running and it connects without problems!?

```
var mysql_link = {
    host : 'localhost',
    port : 3308,
    database: 'nodetest',
    user : 'root',
    password : 'xxx'
};

var connection = mysql.createConnection(mysql_link);

connection.connect(function(err){
    console.log(err);
    if(err != null){
        response.write('Error connecting to mysql:' + err+'\n');
    }
});

connection.end();
```

## error

```
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true }
```

## update

```
root@dyntest-amd-6000-8gb /var/www/node/dyntest # ps ax | grep mysqld
 7928 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep mysqld
28942 ?        S      0:00 /bin/sh /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
29800 ?        Sl    17:31 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log --open-files-limit=65535 --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `ps ax | grep mysqld` I'd like to see what tags mysql is running with

Comment: `--port=3306` vs. `port : 3308,`. Change the port in your script to 3306 and it should work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If this has worked before, my first guess would be that you've already got a copy of your node.js script running in the background which is holding the connection.

I believe connection refused is a tcp/ip error message, rather than something from MySQL which suggests that it is either not running or is running on another port or with sockets.

Could you try telnet'ing to port 3308? To see if the server is running on that port?

```
telnet localhost 3308
```

Can you also try:

```
mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -pxxx
```

Comment: running this from the command line works fine `mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -pxxx`.. How can I kill all node.js scripts?!

Comment: sorry `mysql -hlocalhost -P 3308 -uroot -pxxx` forgot the port.. but it works

Comment: Have now tried to create a `'root'@'%'` with all privileges granted.. same error.. hmm..

Comment: hmm.. I don't know why, but when I change port to the default port 3306 it works!? fact is that in the PHP application it connects to port 3308 and port 3308 is also assigned in my.cnf...

Comment: I'd like to guess PHP is actually using sockets and 3308 in the PHP config is incorrect.

Answer (score 45):

I know this question has been answered, but for me the problem was that the mysql server listens on a Unix socket not on a tcp socket. So the solution was to add:

```
port: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

to the connection options.

Comment: Tested this solution on Ubuntu and it worked for me as well over the other solutions.

Comment: for osx MAMP, the port is /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

Comment: just chiming in for future readers: This solves the issue connecting to mysql on Angstrom Distribution as well via node (at least for me on a BeagleBoneBlack it did) and the path was actually `/tmp/mysql.sock`

Comment: For centos  port: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' works fine, thanks

Comment: Thank you! Worked on Ubuntu 20.04 as well.

Comment: Thanks, @rlemon, it's the same for Mac.

Comment: Works on my Chromebook (Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye))

Answer (score 11):

**Overview**

For anyone else having this problem and is running [mamp](/questions/tagged/mamp). I suspected the problem had to do with the network and not `MySQL` or `Node.js`.

**Solution**

If you open `MAMP` and click `MySQL` in the left navigation panel it will pull up the MySQL options page. In the center of the page you will see a checkbox that says,

> "Allow network access to `MySQL`".

Check this box and then restart your `MAMP`. At this point you can now test your connection to MySQL with `telnet` or a `node.js` script.

*Hint*

Remember you can check which `port` your `MySQL` is running on by opening `MAMP` and clicking the ports link on the left navigation panel.

**Visual Aid**

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Mac OS on M1 MacBook Pro here with MySQL installation via brew:

Changing the host from 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' and creating a different user with a password solved this issue for me.
For some reason I cannot connect to my DB with root user and no password.
I created the new user on MySQL Workbench, but you can create a new user with admin privileges via the mysql CLI also.
Just google it.

This is how my backend looks:

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const app = express();
const port = 3500;

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'admin',
    password: 'admin',
});
db.connect((err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('connected to database');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('server listening on port 3500');
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I only needed to replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0` to make it work.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 did the trick for me. It's weird because it worked with localhost for a while. Mac OS 13.6 Intel

Comment: This also solved my problem running Node on ChromeOS Debian container (penguin).

Answer (score 3):

For some very odd reason, my computer only allowed me to have port 3306 as default port for my connection in order for it to work.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Not sure, but this could be because your Apache Web Server was not running.

Comment: Please do not store credentials in code. Every time someone does that a baby penguin suffers...

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to comment my solution here, just in case there were people as newbie as me in databases.

I was getting this error because I had installed the `mysql` NPM package correctly but **I hadn't installed any implementation of MySQL on my computer** (I didn't know I had to).

I'm using Arch Linux so, in my case, with the NPM package already installed in my project, I did `pacman -Syu mariadb` (MariaDB is the [default implementation](https://www.archlinux.org/news/mariadb-replaces-mysql-in-repositories/) of MySQL in Arch Linux) and then configured it following the [guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MariaDB).

Then, you can use the `root` user you just configured or create a new one to use in your project. For the latter:

- Enter `mysql` CLI by running `mysql -u root -p`.
- Enter the password for `root` user.
- [Create a new database](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-database/) with `CREATE DATABASE mydatabase;`.
- [Create a new user](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-user/) with `CREATE USER test IDENTIFIED BY "testpass";`.
- Grant privileges to `test` user to use your new database with `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydatabase.* TO test@localhost IDENTIFIED BY "testpass";`. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15707789) for more information on this.

And then, in my project, I would have:

```
let connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "test",
    password: "testpass",
    database: "mydatabase"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MAMP please note that mysql default db_port is set to 8889 so you for this purpose I had to change it to 3306 (or whatever your app mysql db_port is set to).

My issue was that node server was connecting using port 3306, so it was giving the error below then crashing but mysql was up and seemed to establishing a connection through localhost, although I couldnt test it because node server was down.

errno: -61,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 3306,
fatal: true

Once I changed the port on MAMP mysql from 8889 to 3306, node server established connection through port 3000 and giving the statement below:

server running on port 3000
The solution is:  2

Answer (score 0):

I use Windows 10 and I have Windows Subsystem For Linux (WSFL). I can execute my project from the WSFL console, but my MySQL is installed in Windows and they can not connect, however when I execute my project from a Windows console then it works without any problems.