# Errors EADDRINUSE and ECONNREFUSED with script

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have script from CSgo roullete.when im try run it show me this error

```
      errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: 'XXX.XX.XXX.XX',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true }
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED XXX.XX.XXX.XX:3306
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:890:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:913:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1061:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/root/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:141:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/root/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:41)
    at PoolConnection.connect (/root/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:123:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (/root/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:45:23)
    at query (/var/www/html/Bot/BOT/site.js:595:7)
    at load (/var/www/html/Bot/BOT/site.js:607:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/Bot/BOT/site.js:59:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
```

i have VPS with Ubuntu 15.10

@update
Now Mysql working good but if i want start this script i got this error.

```
    [Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080]
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 8080 }
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:890:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:913:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1234:14)
    at listen (net.js:1270:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1366:5)
    at Server.listen.Server.attach (/root/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:216:9)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/www/html/Bot/BOT/site.js:618:29)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:224:11)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:198:5)
```

Comment: Look's like the script can't connect, are the port and address correct?

Comment: Check your database configuration ( host,dbname,user auth.. )

Comment: For ECONNREFUSED. read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206801/node-js-mysql-error-econnrefused

Comment: EADDRINUSE:::8080  means that port 8080 is already in use by something.  It could be a crashed nodejs script that has not terminated or let go of the port, or anything else on your system that uses port 8080.

Comment: `lsof -i :8080` check if port is open

Comment: i can change this port to other ?:v

Comment: If i use command lsof -i :8080 i get this: COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    23283 root   18u  IPv6 1270959808      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your mysql server is not running, or running on a different port/interface.

Comment: Now Mysql running and i got this error ^  First post

Comment: Is the mysql server listening on the public interface / IP of your machine (unless the code runs from the same machine) ? Check listening interface with `sudo netstat -tlnp | grep :3306`