# I'm using node.js and I keep getting an error message: Error: connect ETIMEOUT ,

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Node.js to make a networking app equipped with a database and I keep getting an error message:

> Error: connect ETIMEOUT,

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const mysql = require('mysql')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const path = require('path')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

const app = express()

dotenv.config({path:'./.env'})

app.set('view engine', 'hbs')

const publicDirectory = path.join(__dirname, './public')
app.use(express.static(publicDirectory))

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cookieParser())

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
    database: process.env.DATABASE,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD
})

db.connect( (error) => {
    if(error){
     console.log(error)
    }else{
     console.log('DB Connected!')
    }
})

app.use('/', require ('./routes/pages'))
app.use('/auth', require ('./routes/auth'))

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log('Your Connected To Port 5000')
})
```

I store most of my important info in a .env file for security purposes

**.env**

```
DATABASE = bullshit
DATABASE_USER = username
DATABASE_HOST = 192.168.1.3
DATABASE_PASSWORD = password
JWT_SECRET = mysupersecretpassword
JWT_EXPIRES_IN = 90d
JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES = 90
```

**auth.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const authController = require('../controllers/auth')

const router = express.Router()

router.post('/register', authController.register)

router.post('/login', authController.login)

module.exports = router
```

**pages.js**

```
const express = require('express')

const router = express.Router()

router.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.render('index')
})

router.get('/register', (req,res) => {
    res.render('register')
})

router.get('/login', (req,res) => {
    res.render('login')
})

router.get('/profile', (req,res) => {
    res.render('profile')
})

module.exports = router
```

someone told me to change the host to my ip address and so I did. But when I did that's when I got the ETIMEOUT error message. PLEASE HELP

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40868653/etimedout-error-when-querying-mysql-database

Comment: Is your DB connection successful?

Comment: @ChristianLisangola THANKS helped alot

Comment: @JithinZachariah Nvm Christian figured it out