# How can I connect to the server's remote database？it always show me error：ETIMEDOUT

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

[Here is my code]

```
var pool=mysql.createPool({
    host:'43.138.209.122',
    user:'root',
    password:'xxxxxxxx',
    database:'ltest'
});
```

[Navicat panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5XkT.png)

I have never met such problem, please help me!

Hope someone can help me solve my problem! I really need some help! Thank you!!!!

Comment: mysql allows per default only connections via localhost, as exposing the database directly to the internet is a very bad security hazard, if you don't have local the databse, use a REST api to retrieve the data

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a networking issue. Please check for the following:

- Ensure that the port is open using nmap.
- Confirm that there is no firewall blocking the MySQL port.
- Verify that you can ping the server.

Check this question too [ETIMEDOUT error when querying mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40868653/etimedout-error-when-querying-mysql-database)