# Node.js MySQL error: ECONNREFUSED only sometimes

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have read through many similar questions such as [node.js mysql error: ECONNREFUSED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206801/node-js-mysql-error-econnrefused), but none of their solutions have solved my problem. For example, I ran `mysql -hlocalhost -P 3306 -p***` on the command line and it properly connected to my database. It seems that the problem is this specific script. I have another script with the exact same `dbconnection.js` file and it is connecting just fine, like the command line is.

#### dbconnection.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createPool ({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  user: 'root',
  password: ****,
  database: 'test_db',
  dateStrings: true,
  port: 3306
});
module.exports = connection;
```

And this works in one program, but not another. The problem area of the problem script uses the following code:

#### Notifications.js

```
var db = require('../dbconnection');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', function(req,res,next) {
    handleNotification(req.body.value[0].resource);
    res.status(202).end();
});

async function handleNotification(resource) {

    db.query('SELECT of.name, po.PurchaseOrderID FROM order_files AS of \
    INNER JOIN purchase_orders AS po ON po.PurchaseOrderID = of.purchaseOrderID \
    INNER JOIN quotes ON po.PurchaseOrderID = quotes.PurchaseOrderID \
    WHERE quotes.QuoteID=10000', function(err, rows) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      else console.log(rows);
    });
}
```

Yet I can run from bash, `mysql -hlocalhost -P 3306 -p****` and then run the exact query shown and get the results. I can also run this query from another script.

The error received is as follows:
`Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306`

Is there a reason why this specific script would not be able to connect to the database?

Answer (score 1):

The one that is failing is a TCP/IP connection attempt, the one that is succeeding is using a local unix socketfile.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html

> On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name `localhost` specially, in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other network-based programs. For connections to **`localhost`**, MySQL programs attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file. This occurs even if a `--port` or `-P` option is given to specify a port number. To ensure that the client makes a TCP/IP connection to the local server, use `--host` or `-h` to specify a host name value of `127.0.0.1`, or the IP address or name of the local server. You can also specify the connection protocol explicitly, even for `localhost`, by using the `--protocol=TCP` option.

---

That is to say, we can get the same behavior from the MySQL command line client (connection refused), attempting a TCP/IP connection with either

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -p****
```

-or-

```
mysql -h localhost -P 3306 -p**** --protocol=TCP
```

---

MySQL identifies a user by both `user` and `host`.

That is,  `'root'@'localhost'` is a *different* user than `'root'@'%'`. These users have separate passwords, separate permissions, etc.

To get a list of users defined in MySQL Server, we can execute a query like this:

```
SELECT u.user
     , u.host
     , u.password
     , u.plugin
     , u.password_expired 
  FROM mysql.user u
 ORDER BY u.user, u.host
```

Note that if MySQL Server is started without `--skip-name-resolve` option, MySQL will do a reverse lookup of the IP address into a hostname.  That means users will need to be defined as `'user'@'db01.mydomain'` and not `'user'@'127.0.0.1'`

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/host-cache.html

---

If that's not the problem, then it's likely a firewall rule preventing the connection, or the SELinux / AppArmor configuration.

Looking at the reported error message again,

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
```

That doesn't look like the error message we would expect from MySQL Server. That looks more like the network connection was refused, before we even got to MySQL Server.

If MySQL server was not allowing access, we'd expect to be getting an error like this from MySQL Server:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'hostname' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're suggesting the solution is. I tried `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -P 3306 -p***` and that worked, `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -p****` gave me `access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost'`, but that doesn't seem related. I have another script with the exact same dbconnection file and it connects successfuly.

Comment: I was suggesting the problem is that the user is not defined in MySQL Server. I suggested that we test a TCP/IP connection from MySQL command line client. If that's not the issue, then likely the issue is firewall / IPtables rules or SELinux / AppArmor rules.  Actually, given the error message, I'm leaning more towards the AppArmor configuration. (I initially missed the part about one script being able to connect and another not. Answer edited.)

Comment: I am not sure what AppArmor is but a quick search indicates it's limited to ubuntu. I am running this MySQL server on Windows.

Comment: On Windows, there's an issue with churning connections (a lot of connections in a small window of time.) That will exhaust the pool of available ports, and it takes time for Windows to make those ports available again.