# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, windows

So, I followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XuLRKMqozwA

My code is exactly as follows:

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'articles'
});

con.connect();
```

I typed `npm install mysql` while in the directory that my file is in.

Then typed `node new` *new* is the name of the file.

The error I receive is exactly as follows:

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1104:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Test\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\Test\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (C:\Test\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:118:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Test\new.js:10:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Connection._handleProtocolError (C:\Test\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:425:8)
    at Protocol.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Protocol._delegateError (C:\Test\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:390:10)
    at Handshake.<anonymous> (C:\Test\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:153:12)
    at Handshake.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (C:\Test\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:78:12)
    at Protocol.handleNetworkError (C:\Test\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:361:14)
    at Connection._handleNetworkError (C:\Test\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:420:18)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
```

All the other "solutions" to the problem that I could find have not worked for me at all. It is probably something very simple that I am doing wrong because I clearly do not have a lot of experience. Anything will help.

Comment: Just to get it out of the way: are you running a local MySQL server? And are you sure it's using the port 3306?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node.js mysql error: ECONNREFUSED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206801/node-js-mysql-error-econnrefused)

Comment: installing MySQL doesn't run it...as Squirrel suggested, it doesn't appear you've started your server.

Comment: Yeah the problem was as simple as not having the server started. Thanks