# how to run mysql on express js in linux mint

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, service

***I used to run mysql using xampp, do I have to run mysql service?***

I followed this tutorial -> http://mfikri.com/en/blog/nodejs-mysql-crud

I'm confused in step  #2

```
        Server is running at port 8000
/home/aziz/Desktop/Myprojects/backend/crud_fikri/crud-nodejs-mysql/index.js:23
  if(err) throw err;
          ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1136:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/aziz/Desktop/Myprojects/backend/crud_fikri/crud-nodejs-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/aziz/Desktop/Myprojects/backend/crud_fikri/crud-nodejs-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/home/aziz/Desktop/Myprojects/backend/crud_fikri/crud-nodejs-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:118:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/aziz/Desktop/Myprojects/backend/crud_fikri/crud-nodejs-mysql/index.js:22:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1128:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:891:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {

  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
}
```

Comment: I have also tried Git Clone and the results are the same

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the connection to your db was refused. Make sure you are using the correct database account and that it has privileges.

Also make sure to whitelist your app from db.

You need to whitelist the following ips: `127.0.0.1` and `localhost`

this thread can possibly be of help: [node.js mysql error: ECONNREFUSED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206801/node-js-mysql-error-econnrefused)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a MySQL DB running. The easiest way is to [install Docker](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-docker-and-docker-compose-on-linux-mint-19/) on your machine, and use the [official MySQL container](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql).