# Trying to connect live sql server with node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to connect my SQL server with node js but I'm getting the following error.

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.24.68.210:3306
> Error no: -4078

```
var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'hostname',
    user : 'username',
    password: 'pass',
    database: 'db', 
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node.js mysql error: ECONNREFUSED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206801/node-js-mysql-error-econnrefused)

Comment: please share the whole code.