# Error on Creating a table from a Java application

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to create table onto a MySQL Database, but when I click the button to perform, I'm getting the following error on GUI;

> com.mysql.jdbc.exception.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent succesfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Why does this error occur?

Full code on Pastebin; http://pastebin.com/NEic9iP4

Comment: show the codes along with error

Comment: Just edited and updated a link to pastebin for the code, and that's the only error

Comment: possible duplicate of com.mysql.jdbc.exception.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Comment: you are communicating with remote mysql,Am i right?

Comment: yep, give it a host access by what name? Although the wild card % is there

Comment: For remote mysql connections your IP should be having permission.Has your IP granted permission?

Comment: How can I do that and gather my IP?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346305/acces-denied-error-from-java-to-mysql    from this question I have given access to  buiud458_raklar'@'d24-36-33-148.home1.cgocable.net Is that what you mean?

Comment: Your `url` (`dbc:mysql://buiud.com:3306/buiud458_androidhive`) looks wrong, shouldn't it be `jdbc:mysql://buiud.com:3306/buiud458_androidhive`?

Comment: This question described [here][1] I guess.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

```
url = "dbc:mysql://buiud.com:3306/buiud458_androidhive";
```

Change it to :

```
url = "jdbc:mysql://buiud.com:3306/buiud458_androidhive";
```

The error also comes when the Mysql service is not up. But for you I think the error is in your URL