# Connecting to mySQL database in dreamweaver

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

I'm trying to connect Dreamweaver with MySQL databases.

The connection works with username: root; password: has be set to unique value in MAMP.

Databases show up properly in myPHPadmin, Dreamewaver connects with the given Login:Password; however the databases made in myPHPadmin, do not show up.

Additionally there is a Test Database which shows in Dreamweaver which does not show up in myPHPadmin.

Comment: is 'Login:Password' in your example 'root:password'? if not then it may be that the 'Login' does not have privileges on your db. check out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016505/mysql-grant-all-privileges-on-database

Comment: no it is root:password in this example here is more information:

Comment: When i connected mySQL databases to dreamweaver I only saw the default databases, none of the ones I created in myPHPadmin, I am

Comment: running MAMP 2.2  on Mac OS X 10.7.5 Dreamweaver CS6, I am going to the databases icon on the right side of the screen in "App Developer Plus" viewing mode.  I am trying to add a database  with mySQL connection:


sudo mkdir mysql

cd (to get back to root)

sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock

--> SAME ERROR  :(

Why can't Dreamweaver just connect to the databases.? PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Connection Name: registration, mySQL server: localhost, Username: root, Password: my set password, Database <--- here is the error when I click select; it does not show the databaes I made in myPHP admin. called Registration and Dbank;  I'm expecting to see these databases as I can see them in myPHPadmin.  but in Dreamweaver after connecting to mySQL i only see: information_schema. mysql, performance_schema, and test.