# 'SHOW command denied to user' when setting up user permissions

Tags: mysql

I need to grant a user UPDATE and SELECT to two specific column in a db using MYSQL

I used the below command to do this

```
GRANT SELECT (title,new_title,catagory,description,runtime), UPDATE    (title,new_title,catagory,description,runtime) ON database.table1 TO 'user1'@'%' IDENTIFIED  BY    'xxx';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

However when I try to view the table/fields using Sequal Pro I get the following error

```
MySQL said: SHOW command denied to user 'suer1'@'host.x.x.x' for table 'table1'
```

I can see the DB in the database list along with the one table I have granted access to, but I can't read any of the data from it.. Would anyone know how I can fix this error and only view/edit the tables/column I want..?

Answer (score 1):

Your grant will actually work, if you select the specific columns in question:

```
SELECT title, new_title, catagory, description, runtime FROM table1
```

However, a more general query like this will fail with `SELECT command denied to user`:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
```

I believe this may be an issue with the way Sequal Pro tries to get information about the table. It says `MySQL said: SHOW command denied to user`, but despite that the following works:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM table;
```

I'm not sure [which `SHOW` command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show.html) is failing for Sequal Pro.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
GRANT SELECT (col1,col2....), INSERT (col1,col2...) ON mydb.mytbl TO 'someuser'@'somehost'; 
flush privileges;
```

Comment: try this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016505/mysql-grant-all-privileges-on-database

Comment: Query is almost identical to the question, and the linked post grants global privileges. Original question is asking how to get SHOW to work when granting privileges to specific columns.