# Unable to create new databases in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am able to create new databases through the root account. but I need to create new databases using a new user that I have created.

Here is error I'm getting when trying to create a database using the new user

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' to database 'new_db'
```

How can I grant permissions to "user" so it create any number of new databases?

**Update:**

This is also what I tried:

```
mysql> grant all privileges on db.* to 'user'@'%' with create;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'create option' at line 1
mysql>
```

Comment: the below link should help clear your doubt
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016505/mysql-grant-all-privileges-on-database

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html

Answer (score 0):

PHP example:

```
$con = new mysqli("...","...","..."); // CONNECT TO DB WITH ROOT USER

mysqli_query($con, "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON newdb.* TO 'user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION");
```

Command line example:

login with root user, and use this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON newdb.* TO 'user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

This will create a user how is permitted to create new databases (but will give him also all the permissions to do bad stuff, so handle it wise...).

This is for create only:

```
GRANT CREATE ON *.* TO 'newuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
```

Comment: Did you close it with ; ? Tried the statement 5 times

Comment: Yea it cant work without ';'. Same error:                           mysql> create database newDatabase;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' to database 'newDatabase'
mysql>

Comment: ahhh, you need to do that with the root user

Comment: huh? I want the right to "create new databases" with 'user'. How do I get that?

Comment: but to create the user / grant him the rights, you need to have the rights to do that. Later you can create dbs with the user you granted rights to

Comment: Ohh! I'm making the grant statement from root which is working fine - only the create database statement from user, which is throwing the error shown above.

Comment: I don't get the error. You gave the user 'user' create rights, and you are getting an access denied error if you are creating a db with this user?

Comment: Exactly! Isn't that weird?

Comment: In fact it is... :) you might want to try to change the % to localhost, but that's usually not the solution - well might be

Comment: I need access from remote locations. The mysql server is running on a vm.

Comment: Right now, I'm trying from the same machine. But I have a java program on the host machine which will access the database.

Comment: sorry, there's nothing that comes to my mind to solve this. Except using grant all privileges...

Comment: can you try this and look if the rights are correct for the user SELECT * FROM mysql.user;

Comment: Ahh! Create now works from localhost. But I can't perform drop/se;ect operations. This is really weird.

Comment: This was what I expected with the other comment because of localhost. Those drop operations aren't included in create. The user now only can create databases. That's why I wrote the other line with all the privileges.

Comment: Interstingly.. I executed both lines, but I got only create privileges;