# MySQL protect mysql DB

Tags: mysql

I need to setup a MariadB server where I would like the user who will administer the server on a day-to-day basis to have pretty much the ability to do anything - except touch the mysql database, directly manipulate the users table etc.  Here is what I have tried

```
grant all privileges on *.* to myDB@localhost;
revoke super on *.* from myDB@localhost;
revoke all privileges,grant option on mysql.* from mydB@localhost;
show grants for myDB@localhost
```

For the revoke all I have attempted to follow the instructions in the MySQL docs.  However, I get the following error

```
Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'on mysql.* from mydB@localhost' at line 1
```

The other commands do as expected.  If it needs saying - I am not much of a SQL expert.  I just get their in the end by dint of trial and error.  I would be most grateful to anybody who can tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in:

```
grant option on mysql.* from mydB@localhost
```

It should be:

```
grant option on mysql.* to mydB@localhost
```

p.s. remember: **GRANT ON TO, REVOKE ON FROM.**

Answer (score 0):

You are using  `from` statement for the grant option..The statement must be used with grant is `on`.

The code will look like

`grant option on mysql.* on mydB@localhost`

Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016505/mysql-grant-all-privileges-on-database) for more examples