# What are some reasons that I might be getting "0 rows affected" on this query?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

***Backstory:***

I'm trying to create a WordPress theme and am working on the setup part of that theme. I've installed WordPress and the MySQL database on which it is running is named `testdb`. I have a file `setup.php` which looks like

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'testadmin', 'something'); 
if ($con->connect_error)
{
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "<p>Connected to localhost successfully</p>";

if ($con->select_db("testdb"))
{
    echo ("<p>Connected to database</p>");
}
else
{
    die($con->error);
}

if ($con->query("CREATE TABLE mems (id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR (50), title VARCHAR (20), bio VARCHAR (500), sord INT, picfn VARCHAR (100))") === TRUE)
{
    echo("<p>Created table for team members.</p>");
}
else
{
    die($con->error);;
}

$con->close();

?>
```

which is failing on table creation part, as the output is

> Connected to localhost successfully
>
> Connected to database
>
> CREATE command denied to user 'testadmin'@'localhost' for table 'mems'

I assumed it was a privileges problem, so I went into the MySQL command line and ran

```
GRANT ALL on testdb.* to 'testadmin'@'localhost';
```

which outputs

> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

I checked with `SHOW DATABASES;` that indeed the database `testdb` is there, and I checked with `SELECT user FROM mysql.user;` that the user `testadmin` is there. I know the password is  correct.

So what could be the problem?

Comment: try `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON testdb.* TO 'testadmin'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Comment: @Dagon That is [not the best idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5016587/2370483)

Comment: no its bloody dangerous, but for debugging its usefull starting point

Comment: he deleted his account and left - how rude!

Answer (score 1):

If `mems` table already exists, it will fail.

There's an [`IF NOT EXISTS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) clause that will check to see if it exists already.

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
    [(create_definition,...)]
    [table_options]
    [partition_options]
    select_statement
```

`[]` are optional