# PHP mysql PDO connecting with 'user'@'@localhost'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I don't know why, but using PDO MYSQL when trying to connect with:

```
$host='localhost';
$db='contratos';
$user='contratos';
$password='!!contratos';
$link = new \PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$db};charset=utf8", $user, $password);
```

PDO tries to connect adding an extra @ before host:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Accès refusé pour l'utilisateur: 'contratos'@'@localhost' (mot de passe: OUI) in C:\wamp\www\contratos\classes\mysql.php on line 154

I'm using a external class to handle all mysql queries, but, before it was working properly and none of my code was modified.

Is this a PHP, MYSQL, PDO or what error/bug?

*edit: I'm trying to connect, not to create user or grant any rights, I can't connect through PHP, but I'm able to connect using MySQL Workbench*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Grant \*\*all\*\* privileges on database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016505/mysql-grant-all-privileges-on-database)

Comment: Considering you aren't setting the error mode to exceptions in this block, is this really line 154 in your mysql.php class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the char '@' in the error message is a translation error of PDO, for the fr_FR locale.
So you need to ignore this obsolete char and investigate about your mysql user's permissions.

Comment: Thank you, the user@localhost was really deleted, this was the problem, and I was even able to change the language of errors in MySQL.

Answer (score -2):

This works for me:

```
$link = new \PDO("mysql:dbname=$db;host=$host", $user, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
```