# MySQL events_schedule='ON' fails due to privileges

Tags: mysql, cpanel, whm

I’m trying to turn events on. If I execute `SET GLOBAL event_schedule="ON"` , MySQL gives me this error:

> #1227 – Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

[image]

I’m using the root user of my WHM and open cPanel of one of the accounts I have.

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what the problem is. Grant the user `SUPER` privilege.

Comment: i know what it says my friend i am logged in with server root user , then what more super than root user ?

Comment: that was my question why it telling me this while i'm the root ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a difference between Server Root and MySql User Privileges. You need to give yourself MySql privileges. See [MySQL: Grant **all** privileges on database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016505/mysql-grant-all-privileges-on-database)

Also this link has some valuable mysql commands that you will find useful:
http://pentestmonkey.net/cheat-sheet/sql-injection/mysql-sql-injection-cheat-sheet

Comment: you mean i need to give the cpanel root which has the very high privileges  grant all ?

Comment: @AlaaM.Jaddou no you need to give the privileges to the database user. You need to run a query to do that.

Comment: when i'm using server root then i got all the privileges in everything in the server man

Comment: i used to do that with current user in other accounts in the same server :(

Comment: how can i check the privileges to this user ?

Comment: added another link with many queries you can run about users and permissions