# nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection] with root cause

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, annotations

**While i'm trying to save my data, tomcat(7.0.14.0) shows following error.**

```
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
Mar 10, 2016 8:19:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection] with root cause
    java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1075)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3566)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3498)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4004)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1284)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2312)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2122)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:774)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:375)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:289)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:423)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:119)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:57)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1326)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:555)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.saveRole(Unknown Source)
        at com.secl.springmvc.controller.RoleController.saveRole(RoleController.java:43)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:317)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:204)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:182)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:311)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

---

```
> pom.xml

    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>OWOM</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>

        <name>OWOM</name>

        <properties>
            <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>Tomcat</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
            <spring.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <!--       <spring.version>3.2.6.RELEASE</spring.version>-->
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.5.ga</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1.GA</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
            </dependency>
    <!--        <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.sql</groupId>
                <artifactId>jdbc-stdext</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </dependency>-->
            <!--MYSQL Connector -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.13</version>
            </dependency> 
    <!--        <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
                <version>6.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
                                    -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>antlr</groupId>
                <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
                <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <!--          <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>-->
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
    <!--        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>       -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>



        <!--<dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-jcl</artifactId>
                <version>${sl4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${sl4j.version}</version>
            </dependency> -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
                <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <!--            <version>1.0.1B</version>-->
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.15</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.9</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                        <compilerArguments>
                            <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                        </compilerArguments>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>validate</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                                <silent>true</silent>
                                <artifactItems>
                                    <artifactItem>
                                        <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                        <version>6.0</version>
                                        <type>jar</type>
                                    </artifactItem>
                                </artifactItems>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
                <id>hibernate-persistence</id>
                <layout>default</layout>
                <name>Repository for library Library[hibernate-persistence]</name>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>java.net</id>
                <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </project>
```

---

```
> mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml



<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Specifying base package of the Components like Controller, Service, 
    DAO -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.demo.springmvc" />

    <!-- Getting Database properties -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="\WEB-INF\app.properties" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />


        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix">
                <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
            </property>
            <property name="suffix">
                <value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
        </bean>    

    <!-- DataSource -->   

    <!--  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">-->
          <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
            <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
            <property name="username" value="${db.user}"/>
            <property name="password" value="${db.pass}"/>
        </bean>
    <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->   
        <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${hibernate.generate_statistics}</prop>

                </props>
            </property>

     </bean>      
     <!-- Transaction -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />       
    </beans>
```

---

```
> web.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
    <display-name>DEMO</display-name>
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/OWOM/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

---

```
> app.properties

    jdbc.driverClassName =com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    jdbc.url =jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
    db.user =root
    db.pass= =root
    #Hibernate
    hibernate.dialect =org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    hibernate.show_sql =true
    hibernate.format_sql =true
    hibernate.generate_statistics=true
```

Comment: Did you check for correct database credentials or is the connection string correct? `java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Grant \*\*all\*\* privileges on database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016505/mysql-grant-all-privileges-on-database)