# Give all permission by a user(which have all admin rights) to another user

Tags: mysql

I have executed following commands to create new user

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now I have exit from Mysql. Again I have enter in mysql terminal with "newuser"

Then Again I have created new user with following commands

```
CREATE USER 'newuser2'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser2'@'localhost';
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

It returns following error

```
mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to newuser2@localhost identified by 'pass' with grant option;
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'newuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Grant \*\*all\*\* privileges on database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016505/mysql-grant-all-privileges-on-database)

Comment: [To use GRANT, you must have the GRANT OPTION privilege, and you must have the privileges that you are granting.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html)