# from java code how to access mysql installed in remote ubuntu machine for selenium testing?

Tags: java, mysql, selenium, ubuntu

I am automating a website which access data from mySQL. This mySQL is installed on remote Ubuntu machine. I have a .PEM file and the ubuntu IP,that's it. How can I access this mySQL database from Java code, since I am using Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL config file you need to update local host ip(127.0.0.1) to machine ip. Then only you will be able to access the MySQL db from other machine

Answer (score 0):

Click [MySQL: Grant **all** privileges on database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016505/mysql-grant-all-privileges-on-database)])

The above link of stackoverflow will give you details to achieve remote connection of mysql.That is better explained there.