# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES); in eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

im trying to connect to mysql db with java, but im getting this error,
"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"
im using mysql 5.7V
i tried by changing the password, cleaning the project and more but not solved

i tried this also but didn't work

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'root'@'localhost'

my code:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vikas","root","rass");
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15707789/2310289  You need to GRANT privilges

Comment: i tried Grant Privilges but it gives warning as:  0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1287 Using GRANT statement to modify existing user's properties other than privileges is deprecated and will be removed in future release. Use ALTER USER statement for this operation.

Comment: Yeah, but did it work?

Comment: no showing the same error

Comment: Please show the command that you ran

Comment: grant all privileges on vikas.* to root@localhost identified by 'rass';

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20070276/2310289 or try `mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';`  and then `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`

Comment: They assume that the user already exists

Comment: i tried alter user command but got same error, i didn't get this error before it worked fine, suddenly after sometime i again run the program without changing anything and not created other user also but getting this error