# connecting netbeans to a MySql database

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

> java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'Lucky'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO)

What can I do for this error ?I know there are lots of similer questions but non of them worked for me.

Comment: try using a password.  Also see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15707789/2310289

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'Lucky'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '%password%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Execute this with command line or some GUI tool while replacing `%password%` with the real password.