# Cannot connect to MySQL server from external IPV4 address

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, raspberry-pi, ipv4

I have been having a problem with my Java application for a while now. I have tried several options in trying to figure out what is wrong from new drivers to registering the driver to changing permissions on my MySQL database. I only get this problem when I connect with an external IP. I think it might have something to do with IPV6 but I have attempted to disable that on my raspberry pi but when I run "netstat -tlnp" I get this:

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      547/java            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8200            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      547/java            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8009            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      547/java            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5900            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::5900                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

This shows that MySQL server is still running off of tcp6 the port is 8080 I changed it from the standard 3600. My java main class looks like this: `public static String IP; //NULL Variables for the MySQL server IP
    public static final String user = "user"; //Username for the mySQL sever
    public static final String password = "pass"; //Password for the mySQL server TODO figure out how to hide password
    static Connection conn; //NULL connection to get connected to the mySQL server
    public static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in); //Used to get numbers and strings from console

```
/**
 * Runs the program
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Internal or External IP (1 for Internal or 2 for external): ");
    int choice = console.nextInt();
    switch (choice){
    case 1:
        IP = "10.0.0.183";
        break;
    case 2:
        IP = "external ipv4 address";
        break;
    }
    //TRY CATCH method to ensure that the mySQL connection was successful
    try{
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+IP+":8080/mydb",user,password);
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }`
```

This is the error I get when I try to connect to my external IPV4 address `Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.`

Does anyone have a solution or need anything else from me to help solve this problem! Thanks!

Comment: 1) firewall? 2) User table see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15707789/2310289

Answer (score 0):

have you created MySQL user using this 10.0.0.183?
please create MySQL user using this and provide grant and check it

Comment: I have done that. I am able to connect perfectly fine to my server on the 10.0.0.183 IP address but I am having troubles connecting from the "external ipv4 address". Thanks for the response!