# Eclipse : java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, dbconnection

This question has been asked before but none of the solutions are working for me. I'm getting the following error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

when I'm executing the following code

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;



public class MyFirstDBConn {
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/repository";

//  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "root";
   static final String PASS = "pass";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{
            System.out.println("Register the DriverManager with DB driver");


            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER );    

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

            ......
            }
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15707789/2310289

Comment: @ScaryWombat When I try to execute those statements, I get SQL syntax error

Comment: Pardon? What do you mean? Please show your input and errors.

Comment: @ScaryWombat When I try to excute this statement `grant all privileges on repository.* to 'Cortana'@'localhost' identified by 'pass';`
I get `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'identified by 'pass'' at line 1`

Comment: What version of mysql are you using?

Comment: @ScaryWombat 8.0

Comment: Follow the syntax as per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html

Comment: @ScaryWombat That's what I'm trying. Do you think there is something wrong with this statement `grant all privileges on repository.* to 'Cortana'@'localhost' identified by 'pass';`

Comment: maybe lose the `identified..` bit

Comment: @ScaryWombat What do you mean by loose

Comment: See duplicate link

Comment: @ScaryWombat Now it says `Error Code: 1410. You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT`

Comment: As per the link, *Starting with MySQL 8 you no longer can (implicitly) create a user using the GRANT command. Use CREATE USER instead, followed by the GRANT statement:*

Comment: @ScaryWombat Still not working

Comment: *Still not working* - Again, Please show your input and errors.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I'm still getting the same error as the one mentioned above in the post.

Comment: Make sure you sql is running on default port 3306 else add the port info in the url and verify that the username and password is correct and user have access to the db