# Access denied for user "gestioip'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql

I get this error installing [gestioip](http://gestioip.net/). It connects to the DB as root, it creates a db (gestioip db) then it creates an user (the users: gestioip) but this user can't access the DB. (all this via browser on remote machine)

I've tried like similar posts state the following:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO 'gestioip'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

With no effect giving the error present on the topic.
If I login the in console with:

```
mysql -u gestioip -p password
```

it works.

Needless to say that I've followed all the tutorials/installation manuals of the application.

The access to the DB is following:

```
gestioip@localhost
gestioip@127.0.0.1
gestioip@localhost.localdomain
```

Also first line in /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
```

EDIT: 
I installed a ubuntu with GUI and I'm doing the install from the LOCAL browser so no remote problems should arise.

Comment: What version of mysql are you using? Did you check the error logs for a clue

Comment: @RiggsFolly The title in the topic is the line in the "/var/log/mysql/error.log". More more logging info is shown. (apart from the app saying the user couldn't connect)

Comment: Does your `root` user account have a password set?

Comment: You still didn't mention the version of MySQL that you are using?

Comment: mysql version is 5.7.28 and I'm using ubuntu 18.04 LTS. The root account DOES have a password set. (I do login in mysql with it and remotely it creates the specified DB). I do use the command FLUSH PRIVILEGES every time I change privileges.

Comment: I am confused! When you do this `mysql -u gestioip -p password` you are logging on to a LOCAL MySQL But in your question you say **all this via browser on remote machine**

Comment: @RiggsFolly I login in my local machine with the gestioip user and it works. The application installation is done via browser (which is on another machine since this one is a server) and there's where the error is thrown.

Comment: Did you check that the `gestioip` actually has a `localhost` domain setup for it or did the install create a user account with some other domain? Just list all users when logged in as root

Comment: If gestioip is trying to log on from a machine other than the server, then localhost won't work.

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson How can I configure it to work then?

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these to grant access to that user on the db u specified.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO gestioip@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO 'gestioip'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
```

U can look at this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016505/grant-all-privileges-on-database/15707789#15707789)
Or check in MySQL [references guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html#grant-database-privileges).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of localhost use 127.0.0.1

In mysql they are not the same. I imagine your connecting on 127.0.0.1 but permissions are for localhost. That is why the command works. Don't mix and match them