# I accidently removed the master user in mysql and now I dont have any access

Tags: mysql, debian

I accidentally removed the user you set up when installing mysql (Using `DROP USER`), I was assuming that if I created another `'root'@'localhost'` user I would get the permissions back aswell. but it was not the case after I created the user it had no permissions and I tried removing mysql with `apt-get autoremove mysql-server` and then reinstalling but I wasnt prompted the 'set password' promt.
Is there any way I can take the master user back without just reinstalling linux?

Comment: linux user or mysql user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the user alone is not sufficient. You also need to grant the privileges as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016505/mysql-grant-all-privileges-on-database) and the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) with `WITH GRANT OPTION`.

Basically this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Like that you do not loose the data in your database, which would be the case if you used `apt purge` to remove mysql completely.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I was told by a friend after posting this that the command `apt-get purge` existed. autoremove doesn't remove config files but this one does so it solved the issue for me.

Comment: you can reconfigure the server. it will ask and create the master user (with new password) [use -plow flag, to get the questions]