# check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'identified by 'wordpress#demo'' at line 1

Tags: mysql

Where is the syntax error in my SQL statement?

```
mysql> grant all privileges on blog_demo_com.* to 'wordpress'@'localhost' identified by 'wordpress#demo';  
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'identified by 'wordpress#demo'' at line 1
mysql>
```

I checked my SQL statement I really cannot find the issue.

---

**EDIT-01**

my MySQL version:

```
mysql  Ver 8.0.25 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

Comment: you don't need to add the identified by part , try it this way grant all privileges on blog_demo_com.* to 'wordpress'@'localhost' you can refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016505/mysql-grant-all-privileges-on-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `identified by` syntax is not supported by MySQL 8.x: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html

```
GRANT
    priv_type [(column_list)]
      [, priv_type [(column_list)]] ...
    ON [object_type] priv_level
    TO user_or_role [, user_or_role] ...
    [WITH GRANT OPTION]
    [AS user
        [WITH ROLE
            DEFAULT
          | NONE
          | ALL
          | ALL EXCEPT role [, role ] ...
          | role [, role ] ...
        ]
    ]
}
```